# jQuery Simple Slider doesn't respond to touch events

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, touch

I'm using the jQuery plugin Simple Slider ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc4ujsbj/)) but on touch devices, it is not possible to drag the range value handle.

I tried editing the portion of code from simple-slider.js below by replacing "mousedown, mousemove, and mouseup" with the corresponding touch values of "touchstart/move/end" - but that didn't work.

How can I get this working on touch devices?

```
this.track.bind("mousedown touchstart", function (e) {
    return i.trackEvent(e)
}), this.settings.highlight && this.highlightTrack.bind("mousedown touchstart", function (e) {
    return i.trackEvent(e)
}), this.dragger.bind("mousedown touchstart", function (e) {
    if (e.which !== 1) return;
    return i.dragging = !0, i.dragger.addClass("dragging"), i.domDrag(e.pageX, e.pageY), !1
}), e("body").bind("mousemove touchmove", function (t) {
    if (i.dragging) return i.domDrag(t.pageX, t.pageY), e("body").css({
        cursor: "pointer"
    })
}).bind("mouseup touchend", function (t) {
    if (i.dragging) return i.dragging = !1, i.dragger.removeClass("dragging"), e("body").css({
        cursor: "auto"
    })
}), this.pagePos = 0, this.input.val() === "" ? (this.value = this.getRange().min, this.input.val(this.value)) : this.value = this.nearestValidValue(this.input.val()), this.setSliderPositionFromValue(this.value), r = this.valueToRatio(this.value), this.input.trigger("slider:ready", {
    value: this.value,
    ratio: r,
    position: r * this.slider.outerWidth(),
    el: this.slider
}
```

Here's the link to the plugin's info: http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following updated code for Simple Slider supports both mouse and touch events:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jeffedsell/jquery-simple-slider/master/simple-slider.js